# Linux CentOS dedicated server, process is dissapearing from WHM process manager

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I have a script running on my dedicated server /usr/bin/php/home/user/public_html/myscript.php. When I log in to WHM/Process Manager, sometimes this script disappears from the list. Also, when I log in to terminal, I see via "top" command that mysqld process is taking 15%-20% of CPU, and 3% RAM. Sometimes, this process takes up to 150% of CPU (and as I saw, this script disappears when mysqld takes on CPU), according to top command. I'm wondering is there any way that I can trace my script, is the script working well or it struggles sometimes? I'm concerned because this script is disappearing every 10 seconds so I don't know if it is really working or there is some configuration issue on server.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to edit the script to print something when it completes.  For example, add at the proper location (likely at or near the end), and within proper PHP syntax:

```
Echo "I finished successfully!";
```

Run it several times and and look for this output each time.  Perhaps if you can post the script (or relevant portions of it), someone can help debug it further.

Another idea is to have the script write to a log file, and check the log file.  You could even get creative and write a script to call your script many times, and check for the output each time.